# pppd: CHAP authentication failure - sometimes

Tags: linux, internet

I got a group of embedded devices (running Linux) repeatedly connecting to an ISP over a ordinary analog PPP connection.

Sometimes (every third connection time) the pppd authentication breaks up with a chap error. Here are the according log lines:

```
Nov  2 13:43:05 40-363DA691-240 daemon.notice pppd[8023]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyACM0
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xcb5bf37> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <mru 1514> <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x444317ad> <pcomp> <accomp> <mrru 1514> <endpoint [null]>]
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: sent [LCP ConfRej id=0x1 <mrru 1514>]
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xcb5bf37> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <mru 1514> <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x444317ad> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <mru 1514> <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0x444317ad> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: rcvd [CHAP Challenge id=0x3 <bf2b15282cf4f6672f1b809a251bd731>, name = "HiPer"]
Nov  2 13:43:06 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: sent [CHAP Response id=0x3 <69cd88a27098f6c3e961f49f0cec74fb>, name = "Sunrise"]
Nov  2 13:43:39 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: rcvd [CHAP Failure id=0x3 "\37777777677+\025(,\37777777764\37777777766g/\033\37777777600\37777777632%\033\377777777271"]
Nov  2 13:43:39 40-363DA691-240 daemon.info pppd[8023]: CHAP authentication failed: M-?+^U(,M-tM-vg/^[M-^@M-^Z%^[M-W1
Nov  2 13:43:39 40-363DA691-240 daemon.err pppd[8023]: CHAP authentication failed
Nov  2 13:43:39 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "Failed to authenticate ourselves to peer"]
Nov  2 13:43:39 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x4]
Nov  2 13:43:39 40-363DA691-240 daemon.debug pppd[8023]: sent [LCP TermAck id=0x4]
```

Note: Username (Sunrise) and password (freesurf) aren't confidential (public swiss ISP, payment by telephone line billing) and always the same -> Therefore the reason for this can't be any mistyped auth data.

Could anybody help me in interpreting these log lines (CHAP Failure id=0x3)? I'm tending to accuse the ISP for this auth failures. Am I right?

thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I accused the ISP for the periodical login problems. They accepted their blame without any contradiction. The Point-Of-Presence (POP) sometimes accepts calls physically (off-hook) but there is any process (PPP) serving the established connection.

The ISP recommends: Wait for at least one minute till redialing and use the direct phone number to the POP instead of the unique Swiss collector number.